# Azure Stream Analytics and Event Order

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to set up a ASA job. My use case is that, I receive telemetry data from vehicles in the field. They transmit various attributes of the vehicle. e.g. Engine currently on or off

[image]

This data goes to IoT Hub and then ASA consumes it.

My problem is with the inputs coming out of sequence. For example, in the above diagram #9 came before #8.

He is my ASA Query

```
With AllSpeeder AS {
SELECT
    telemetry.deviceId as vehicleid,
    telemetry.enginestatus as currentenginestatus,
    telemetry.datetime as currenttime,
    Last(telemetry.containerdt) over (partition by telemetry.vehicleid limit duration(day,7) 
          when (telemetry.enginestatus = 'On2Off')) as engineontime
FROM
    theiot
Timestamp by cast ( telemetry.containerdt as datetime)
where
    telemetry.enginestatus = 'Off' or telemetry.enginestatus = 'On2Off' 
}

 SELECT * INTO theblob FROM AllSpeeder
```

But the above query (TimeStamp by) did not fix it.

I experimented with Event Order in ASA But still 8 and 9 above are not getting reordered.
[image]

Comment: Konstantin Zoryn reply in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17e4fa7d-3ba2-4fec-b558-aaddf5381c44/azure-stream-analytics-amp-event-ordering?forum=AzureStreamAnalytics got me back in right path. Now it is reordering. I have asked him to answer this question here. So i can mark that as answer.